# Can't export Organization logs to custom project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to export Google Cloud Organization's logs to the _Default log bucket from **another project**. It seems impossible right now. There's not a single clue or error telling me why.
What I've tried so far is to:

- Export to pub/sub topic
- Export to custom GCS bucket
- **Export to _Default logging bucket from another project. // THIS is the case I'd lake to work on**.
- Export to custom logging bucket from another project.

The same behavior is observed in all those cases: **no logs are exported at all**.

I'm using Terraform for this task and everything seems fine in configurations.
I'm giving also the correct IAM permissinons to the service account writer identity:

```
org-logs-role = {
  members = [
    google_logging_organization_sink.organization_sink.writer_identity
  ],
  role_id = "roles/logging.bucketWriter"
}
```

And the sink code is:

```
resource "google_logging_organization_sink" "organization_sink" {
  name = "gbl-snk-${var.project}-${var.environment}-3-gcp"
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/${var.project}/locations/global/buckets/_Default"
  org_id = local.organization_id
  include_children = true
  filter = "protoPayload.serviceName=\"admin.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"cloudidentity.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"login.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"iam.googleapis.com\""
}
```

When listing the sink, it shows up in the organization, but no logs are arriving to the _Default bucket (I'm hiding the project real name)

```
gcloud logging sinks list --organization={organization_id}

NAME                            DESTINATION                                                                           FILTER
gbl-snk-{project}-global-3-gcp  logging.googleapis.com/projects/{project}/locations/global/buckets/_Default           protoPayload.serviceName="admin.googleapis.com" OR protoPayload.serviceName="cloudidentity.googleapis.com" OR protoPayload.serviceName="login.googleapis.com" OR protoPayload.serviceName="iam.googleapis.com"
```

What am I doing wrong? I can see the logs in the Organization's Logging console, but they are not arriving to the {project} _Default bucket.

**P.S.:** I tried to copy/paste (just in case) this code (changing the bucket name and the org. id, of course) and the same happens. No errors, but no logs in the destination bucket.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/logging_organization_sink

The kind of logs I want to see are events like CreateUser or DeleteUser, from the filters specified.

Any help will be welcome.

I'd like to state that his is not (in my opinion) a duplicate of:
[Google Cloud Logs not exporting to storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790949/google-cloud-logs-not-exporting-to-storage)

Because everything's right and no errors arise at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a write permission issue. Can you perform this command

```
gcloud logging describe gbl-snk-{project}-global-3-gcp --organization={organization_id}
```

In the result, get the `writerIdentity` service account value. Go to your target project, in the IAM page grant it as Logs Writer or Logs Bucket Writer (see the difference [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control)).

It should work better then.

In Terraform, you can get the writer Identity like that

```
google_logging_organization_sink.organization_sink.writer_identity
```

Comment: Assigning the role logging.logWriter made it all work! It is explained in the link you provided. I'm adding the anchor: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#writing. I don't know why I didn't see this initially. Both Logs Writer and Logs Bucket Writer roles seem to be needed. Thank you very much, Guillaume.